# How to convert DateTime to just Date in LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice-calc, date-time

In LibreOffice, Calc under Linux, I have a table with DateTime values (eg. 2011-06-15T15:37:56+00:00).  How shall I convert these values to just Date values (eg. 2011-06-15)?  I suspect it is very simple..

Comment: Have you tried =INT(A1), where A1 is the cell with the combined Date-Time value?

Comment: Ancient question that just got bumped.  One thing that isn't clear (and future readers may have different needs):  Is the actual requirement to work with just the date, so different times of day are all treated the same, or simply to display only the date?  If you need to eliminate the time (for sorting, filtering, or date/time math), using  INT or DATEVALUE, as described in the answers, does that.  If it is simply a matter of displaying just the date, that can be done with formatting, and the data doesn't need to be altered.

Answer (score 3):

Having issues as well (4.0.2.2 with English (US) locale): It somehow won't recognize the long ISO format for dates; only if I edit the date and remove the time. I've read about **date acceptance patterns**, but couldn't get them to work (why wouldn't it work by default to begin with?).

As a workaround (note: data will be lost!) you could use search and replace:

- Select the cells with dates and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.
- Use the search pattern `(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\+\d{2}:\d{2}`.
- The replacement is `$1`.
- Tick **Regular expressions** (click on **More Options** if you don't see it).
- Click **Replace All**.
- It should now recognize the dates (but you no longer have to format them anyway).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I have tried that without success!

Comment: Okay, just saw that I've got Calc installed in my virtual machine. Having a look - now I'm curious... :)

Comment: @Lars: It works exactly like Mario wrote (+1)

Comment: @duDE It should, but it doesn't, because it somehow doesn't recognize the dates (and considers them string input).

Comment: @Mario With a little modification your resplace worked fine. Se answer below

Comment: The Search expression (reg exp) should be:
([:digit:]{4}-[:digit:]{2}-[:digit:]{2})T[:digit:]{2}:[:digit:]{2}:[:digit:]{2}\+[:digit:]{2}:[:digit:]{2}
And the Replace, just as Mario said:
$1
Then it worked.  I think the syntax differ a bit from Excel.
However it should indeed be possible to make a normal conversion of the DateTime type to a Date type .. can it be a bug in LibOffice Calc?
 
Thanks.

Comment: Hm? I've used `\d` in LibreOffice Calc without problems. Maybe this differs from version to version as well, but I think it should accept both. As for the detection, this might indeed be a bug or some oversight (or us misunderstanding the whole thing). At least I don't see any reason for not supporting the long ISO format.

Comment: It's actually a workaround but I wouldn't consider it a direct answer, so wouldn't hurt to keep the question open for a bit longer. Maybe we're both missing something important.

Comment: @duDE: Let's wait for a day or to, as Mario suggested.   That's wise.

Answer (score 3):

it is quite more simple...  just use the function `=DATEVALUE(a)` with "a" the cell with your text DateTime. Then format your resulting cell as wanted.

The same way if you want just the "time" section, use `=TIMEVALUE(a)`

and if you want in one cell the entire date and time values, not as text but as  time and date values, use  `=DATEVALUE(a) + TIMEVALUE(a)`   and format as wished.

regards!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. No need for REGEX here.

Comment: @ButtleButkus 100% agreed. However, it will not work unless the input is already string. (Why oh why)

Comment: Turns out if you have a full datetime, use `TRUNC()` to cut off the time-of-day